# Scala copy method in supertype

Tags: scala

I have an abstract class (this is an analogous example) `Printer` which prints the supplied argument unless it fails to pass a filter.  `Printer` is contravariant w.r.t. its generic type `T`.

```
class Printer[-T] {
  val filters: Seq[Function2[T => Boolean]]

  def print(t: T): Unit {
    if (filters.forall(_(t))) doPrint(t)
  }
  def doPrint(t: T): Unit
}
```

I now have 20 subclasses of `Printer` -- one for Strings, Ints, etc.  Since `Printer` is contravariant, `filters` must be a `val`.  However if I want a method of `Printer` to add a filter it needs to be immutable.

```
def addFilter[TT <: T](t: TT): Printer[TT]
```

Unfortunately I now need to implement this method in each of my 20 subclasses.  Is there any way around this?

Update: Also, in `addFilter`, I don't know how I can return the subclass instead of the superclass `Printer`.  For example, if I called `addFilter` on a `StringPrinter` I would ideally get the type `StringPrinter` back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe following is a bit of a departure from the way you have coded your `Printer`, but potentially could fulfil your intentions. Note that this way of coding your class enables a greater separation of concerns: you can define filters and print implementations (the `doPrint` argument) independently of how they are being used:

```
case class Printer[T](val filters: List[Function1[T, Boolean]], val doPrint: T => Unit) {
  def print(t: T): Unit = {
    if (filters.forall(_(t))) doPrint(t)
  }

  def addFilter[TT <: T](f: TT => Boolean): Printer[TT] = copy(f :: filters)
}
```

Note that I haven't needed to specify contravariancy here, not sure if that will be an issue for you.

To use the class, you don't need to subclass, just pass suitable arguments into the constructor (actually, the companion `apply` factory method provided for free for case classes) - eg:

```
case class Foo(x: Int)
val fooChk1: Foo => Boolean = (f: Foo) => f.x != 1
val fooPrinter1 = Printer(fooChk1 :: Nil, (f: Foo) => println(s"Foo: x = ${f.x}"))

val fooChk3: Foo => Boolean = (f: Foo) => f.x != 3
val fooPrinter2 = fooPrinter1.addFilter(fooChk3)

val foo3 = Foo(3)
fooPrinter1.print(foo3) // Prints 'Foo: x = 3'
fooPrinter3.print(foo3) // Prints nothing
```

There is also a fair bit of scope for using implicits here, too - both for parameters to `Print` (eg. change the constructor to `(val filters: List[Function1[T, Boolean]])(implicit val doPrint: T => Unit)`), and for specific `Print[X]` variants.

Comment: Good example.  I don't think it quite works for me.  I use the subclassing because the functionality is often quite complicated and I create instances of the subclasses specified in a DSL using reflection.

Comment: Thinking about it more, separation of concerns might be my problem.  Maybe I'll make a `ConstraintedPrinter[T](printer: Printer[T], filters: Seq[T => Boolean])`.